# One topcoder puzzle about IntersectingConvexHull

Tags: c++, algorithm

I first asked this question four hours ago. In fact, I have searched about this question for more than 6 hours but still can't understand.

This question is about giving you n points by giving you x[n] and y[n]. You should find two subset of those points, whose convex hull are intersected. Your response should be the number of cases satisfying the rules above.

> You are given a finite set S of points in the plane. For each valid i,
> one of those points has coordinates (x[i], y[i]). The points are all
> distinct and no three of them are collinear.
>
> Below, CH(s) denotes the convex hull of the set s: that is, the
> smallest of all convex polygons that contain the set s.  We say that
> the ordered pair (s1, s2) is interesting if the following conditions
> are satisfied:
>
> 1.s1 is a subset of S
>
> 2.s2 is a subset of S
>
> 3.the sets s1 and s2 are disjoint (i.e., they have no elements in common)
>
> 4.the intersection of the convex hulls CH(s1) and CH(s2) has a positive area Note that some points from S may remain unused (i.e.,
> they will be neither in s1, nor in s2).   You are given the
> coordinates of all points: the s x and y. Please compute and return
> the number of interesting pairs of sets, modulo 10^9 + 7.
>
> Examples
>
> {1,0,-1,-1,0,1} {1,2,1,-1,-2,-1}
>
> Returns: 14
>
> We have 14
> solutions:
>
> s1 = {0,1,3}, s2 = {2,4,5} s1 = {0,2,3}, s2 = {1,4,5} s1 =
> {0,1,4}, s2 = {2,3,5} s1 = {0,2,4}, s2 = {1,3,5} s1 = {1,2,4}, s2 =
> {0,3,5} s1 = {0,3,4}, s2 = {1,2,5} s1 = {1,3,4}, s2 = {0,2,5} s1 =
> {0,2,5}, s2 = {1,3,4} s1 = {1,2,5}, s2 = {0,3,4} s1 = {0,3,5}, s2 =
> {1,2,4} s1 = {1,3,5}, s2 = {0,2,4} s1 = {2,3,5}, s2 = {0,1,4} s1 =
> {1,4,5}, s2 = {0,2,3} s1 = {2,4,5}, s2 = {0,1,3}

There are many solution which I can't understand, the following is one of them. for example, what's the ccw for? the result composed of two part, why?
Could you provide me some algorithm name, some keyword is also OK, so that I can search it in detail on google?

Here is one sample code to solve this problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const long long mod=1000000007ll;
struct IntersectingConvexHull{
    public:
        int count(vector<int> x, vector<int> y){
            int n = x.size();
            long long P2[110];
            P2[0]=1ll;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                P2[i]=P2[i-1]*2%mod;
            }
            long long C[110][110];
            for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
                C[i][0]=C[i][i]=1ll;
                for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
                    C[i][j]=(C[i-1][j-1]+C[i-1][j])%mod;
                }
            }
            long long X[100],Y[100];
            for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
                X[i]=x[i];
                Y[i]=y[i];
            }
            long long ans=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(i==j)continue;
    
                    int c1=0,c2=0;
                    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                        if(k==i||k==j){
                            continue;
                        }
                        long long ccw=(X[i]-X[k])*(Y[j]-Y[k])-(Y[i]-Y[k])*(X[j]-X[k]);
                        if(ccw<0){
                            c1++;
                        }
                        else{
                            c2++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(c1>=2&&c2>=2){
                        ans+=((P2[c1]+mod-c1-1)%mod)*((P2[c2]+mod-c2-1)%mod)%mod;
                        ans%=mod;
                    }
                }
            }
            long long A=0ll;
            for(int i=3;i<=n;i++){
                for(int j=3;j<=n-i;j++){
                    A+=C[n][i]*C[n-i][j]%mod;
                    A%=mod;
                }
            }
            return (A+mod-ans)%mod;

        }
};
```

Comment: Please don't post images for code. Post the code instead.

Comment: but i can't copy them because of limitation of website.

Comment: Then type the code manually by looking at the image.

Comment: ok, wait some minutes.

Comment: I have typed it again

Comment: Much better. I looked at the code but I could not figure out what it does. Hopefully somebody will be able to figure it out and help you.

Comment: The sign of `ccw` tells you whether triangle `(i, j, k)` is a clockwise or counterclockwise triangle.

Comment: @AnT do you know why is P2[c1]+mod-c1-1 following ccw?

Comment: The usual approach is to define an upper and lower hull (wrt the y-coordinate) by sorting the points by x and then building up an array that contains the points that lie on that hull by incrementally adding a point, checking if it forms an angle to the right with the last two points and deleting points from the array if necessary. Dunno if that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sets must have at least three points for the intersection of hulls to have nonzero area. The code computes the number of partitions meeting this criterion minus the number of partitions with zero intersection area. (`P2` is powers of two. `C` is binomial coefficients.)

The intersection of two convex hulls has zero area if and only if there is a line that separates the two hulls ([Hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem)). I think that we need an extension of this result, actually, that (under the right assumptions) there are exactly two lines that separate the hulls and touch both.

The last loop computes the minuend. The one before, computing the subtrahend, is where the geometric considerations come in. The code loops over all pairs of points and, considering the line through them, counts the number of points on each side via a signed area test. It adds to the result the number of ways to choose two or more points from each side, thus ensuring that, if we include the first point in the pair in one hull and the second point in the pair in the other, we get two hulls supported by and separated by the line.

I have no idea how this code copes with degenerate inputs (two duplicate points, three collinear points).